# Fullpage JS scroll debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js, debouncing

I am using `Fullpage.js` library and it works fine out of the box, but I need to adjust some settings. I've set `scrollingSpeed: 300,`
and now it behaves weirdly.

When a default value is used (it is `700`) everything works fine, but when I set `scrollingSpeed` to lower value the problem appears.
While scrolling most of times multiple sections are scrolled at once for example one section is skipped.

I've not found any option to change this behavior, I need something like debounce, throttle or just change scroll sensitivity.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a well known fullPage.js issue as you can see [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1654).

It hasn't been solved so far.